# How do you use package in elm? ( I want to use elm-pagination package )

Tags: elm

I am a super Elm beginner and trying to build pagination function in my application.
I found a package that seems pretty nice, but I don't really understand how to use it.

The package is below.
https://github.com/jschomay/elm-paginate

It seems like that you have to write import statement but when I do it, an error occurs like below.

```
UNKNOWN IMPORT - The Example module has a bad import:

    import Paginate

I cannot find that module! Is there a typo in the module name?

The "source-directories" field of your elm.json tells me to only look in the src
directory, but it is not there. Maybe it is in a package that is not installed
yet?
```

I think you only have to write import statement or launch package get command on your terminal in other programing language.
But I don't know how it is done in Elm.

Does anybody know how to use other packages like elm-pagination??

Comment: Did you install the package with `elm install`?

Comment: thank you very much for answering my question!
I didn't know you have to run `elm install` command!
I tried it and it works fine now!

Comment: @RobinZigmond, you should make it a proper answer to the question. (and tonteki should accept it, as it solved their problem)

Answer (score 0):

Install the package with:

```
elm install jschomay/elm-paginate
```